# Best practice for "global" variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I put all my code in NS, similar to how jQuery is structured.  I have a few variables global to NS, that I would like to enclose and then make accessible like this -> `Global.variable_name`.

Below is the way I did it.  Is this good practice?  Is there a better way to do this where I do not have to call `var Global = new GlobalMaker()`

I use all capitals for global CONSTANTS.

```
var NS = ( function ( window, undefined ) { /* all my code is here */ } )( )

/** (including this code)
 *GlobalMaker
 */

var GlobalMaker = function()
{
    this.tag_array = [];
    this.current_tag;
    this.validate_input_on;
    this.JSON_ON = 1;                              // selector between JSON and LON
    this.GATEWAY = 'class.ControlEntry.php';       // for Ajax calls
    this.PICTURES = '../pictures/';                // for composing tweets
    this.PASS = 0;
    this.FAIL = 1;
    this.NOTDEFINED = 2;
};
var Global = new GlobalMaker();

/**
 *Global 
 */

var Global = 
{
    tag_array:          [],
    current_tag:        0,
    validate_input_on:  0,
    JSON_ON:            1,                             
    GATEWAY:            'class.ControlEntry.php',       
    PICTURES:           '../pictures/',                
    PASS:               0,
    FAIL:               1,
    NOTDEFINED:         2
}
```

Comment: If the object is *just* a collection of properties like that, you could simply initialize it with an object literal.

Comment: There's no need to call `new`> You can just build an object literal. `var Global = {...properties...};`

Comment: Well you are creating a new instance everytime you want to access a global variable, you could make it static, but other than that, it seems good. You might find this useful: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

Comment: @GuyMontag: Just like the other properties. `tag_array: [],`, and no, the properties need values. You can use `null` as a substitute.

Comment: your second snippet will not work , you have typos all over the place , a semi colon , an you have to give current_tag and validate_input_on  a value.

Comment: @GuyMontag: Sorry, but what's your actual question?

Comment: That looks fine now.  But you can also skip those properties you don't want to define ahead of time, and then update the object with them when you know their values.

Comment: Furthermore your question doesnt make sense. encapsulation means HiDDEN , or "access controlled" , global means available everywhere. ie in the window scope in ES < 5.

Comment: Well, once, everytime you use it, it could be only once, but that's what static classes are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the equivalent, without using a constructor function:

```
var Global = {
    tag_array: [],
    // current_tag, // huh?
    // validate_input_on, // huh?
    JSON_ON: 1,
    GATEWAY: 'class.ControlEntry.php',
    PICTURES: '../pictures/',
    PASS: 0,
    FAIL: 1,
    NOTDEFINED: 2
};
```

But I don't understand the second two declarations that have no initialization.

Note, though, that if you do this as you indicate above, this Global object is available only within that outer `Arc` function expression.  It's not truly global.  Also note that the use of '`global`' (lowercase) is pretty common; you might want to consider a different varialbe name (perhaps '`constants`'?)